# Sql Command Not Working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I wrote the following code, but nothing is being inserted into the database.

I tried changing the SA password in the connection string to something incorrect and the code isn't catching the exception.

What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstName = TextBox1.Text;
    lastName = TextBox2.Text;
    collegeName = TextBox3.Text;
    majorSubject = TextBox4.Text;
    emailAddress = TextBox5.Text;
    phoneNumber = TextBox6.Text;
    address = TextBox7.Text;
    city = TextBox8.Text;
    state = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    zipCode = TextBox9.Text;
    interestDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

    string completedString = " " +firstName+ " "  +lastName+ " "  +collegeName+ " "  +majorSubject+ " "  +emailAddress+ " "  +phoneNumber+ " "  +address+ " "  +city+ " "  +state+ " "  +zipCode+ " " +interestDate+ ".";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + completedString + "');", true);

    try
    {

    string strCon = "Data Source=OMIW2310.orthman.local;Initial Catalog=CollegeRecruiting;User Id=sa;Password=myPassword;";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {

        string strSQL = "USE CollegeRecruiting INSERT INTO Students (lastName, firstName, collegeName, majorSubject, emailAddress, phoneNumber, address, city, state, zip, interestDate) VALUES ('" + firstName + "', '" + lastName + "', '" + collegeName + "', '" + majorSubject + "', '" + emailAddress + "', '" + phoneNumber + "', '" + city + "', '" + state + "', '" + zipCode + "', '" + interestDate + "')";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

       } 
   }
   catch (SqlException ex)
   {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
   }

   ClearTextBoxes();        

}
```

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to my friend `Bobby'); DROP TABLE students; --`.

Comment: I really hope the password to your sa account isn't actually "myPassword". If it is, I'm sure your students will happily change it if they see it... You need to look into SQL Injection attacks as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As stated by the OP in the comments. Once the `try-catch` was resolved it was discovered that it just a mismatched number of fields and values.**

Just an FYI, you can get rid of this:

```
USE CollegeRecruiting
```

It's already using the right database because of the connection that you created above it.

Finally, please don't leave yourself open to SQL Injection. Rewrite your code to be something more along these lines:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (@field1...)"), c)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtField1.Text);

    c.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @CryptoJones, are you getting an exception? If you put a break point on that line, do you even get there?

Comment: Once I corrected my try/catch statement it showed me I had a mismatched number of INSERTS/VALUES.

Thank You for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `USE CollegeRecruiting` before the `INSERT` statement.

Also use [parameterized](http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/) queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

For example:

```
  command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students (lastName, firstName VALUES (@lastName, @firstname);";

  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
```

**Note:** You are entering the `last name` in the first name column and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Once I corrected the catch statement, the resulting error showed me I had a mismatched number of INSERTS/VALUES.

I will now parameterize my query to prevent SQL Injection Attacks.

Thank You for the help everyone!

CJ